# OpenGL/GLSL Color Attachment range

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, framebuffer

Is there a way, in GLSL/OpenGL textures, to store floats which are higher than 1 or lower than 0 ?
I'm working on a deferred rendering framework but when i try to store the positions as non-homogenious values (first shader) i get only values between 0-1 in my phong shader (second shader).
Same with normals, the light was displaying wrong.
The way to fix this was in the first shader :

```
gbuffer[x] =normal *0.5 +1. and in phong : normal * 2. - 1.   //(non-)homogenious    conversation
```

But I don't want to use this method.

So my current texture format is RGB. I tried RGB_16 but then I get a black window.

Comment: Have you looked into floating point textures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GL_RGB16` is still a normalized format, which means that the sampled value is between 0.0 and 1.0.

What you need to get a range outside of [0.0, 1.0] is a floating point texture. The formats with 3 components are `GL_RGB16F` for 16-bit float components and `GL_RGB32F` for 32-bit float components. Those two formats are not guaranteed to be supported for render targets, though (see table 8.12 in GL 4.5 spec). You will need to use their 4-component versions if you  need to render to them: `GL_RGBA16F` or `GL_RGBA32F`.

If you still have a fixed range for your values, the approach you tried where you map your given range into a [0.0, 1.0] range by applying an offset/scale actually looks very valid to me. Using for example `GL_RGBA16` gives you 16 bits of precision, while you get only 12 bits of precision from `GL_RGBA16F` with the same memory usage, since 4 bits are used for the exponent.